# В чем может быть ошибка при деплое Spring Boot приложения на vps?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring-boot

Гитхаб проекта:https://github.com/DeadSidert/telegramBotMoney
Первый раз деплою приложения.

Stackrace:

```html
07:34:41.413 [main] INFO com.nikita.App - Starting App on dsde1081-22288.fornex.org with PID 68272 (/root/telegramBotMoney.jar started by root in /root)
07:34:41.416 [main] DEBUG com.nikita.App - Running with Spring Boot, Spring
07:34:41.417 [main] INFO com.nikita.App - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
07:34:41.418 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class com.nikita.App
07:34:41.573 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4461c7e3
07:34:41.589 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnn         otationProcessor'
07:34:41.703 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/bot/Bot.class]
07:34:41.732 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repos         itory/JpaChannelCheckRepository.class]
07:34:41.734 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repos         itory/JpaChannelRepository.class]
07:34:41.735 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repos         itory/JpaPaymentRepository.class]
07:34:41.736 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repos         itory/JpaUserRepository.class]
07:34:41.742 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/service/Channel         CheckService.class]
07:34:41.743 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/service/Channel         Service.class]
07:34:41.747 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/service/Payment         Service.class]
07:34:41.748 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/service/UserSer         vice.class]
07:34:41.928 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
07:34:41.952 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Scanning for JPA repositories in packages com.nikita*.
07:34:42.005 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repository/Jpa         ChannelCheckRepository.class]
07:34:42.005 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repository/Jpa         ChannelRepository.class]
07:34:42.006 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repository/Jpa         PaymentRepository.class]
07:34:42.006 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/repository/Jpa         UserRepository.class]
07:34:42.125 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 169ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
07:34:42.276 [main] DEBUG org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext - Class org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.BotSession already registered
07:34:42.276 [main] DEBUG org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext - Class org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.Webhook already registered
07:34:42.279 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'emBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor'
07:34:42.293 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcesso         r'
07:34:42.294 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
07:34:42.296 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotat         ionProcessor'
07:34:42.299 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotation         Processor'
07:34:42.308 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnot         ationProcessor'
07:34:42.311 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotat         ionProcessor'
07:34:42.315 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurati         on'
07:34:42.351 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'app'
07:34:42.356 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'bot'
07:34:42.422 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'channelService'
07:34:42.426 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jpaChannelRepository'
07:34:42.540 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.b         eans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bot' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/bot/Bot.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through co         nstructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'channelService' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.         jar!/com/nikita/service/ChannelService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating          bean with name 'jpaChannelRepository' defined in com.nikita.repository.JpaChannelRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on App: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#207b8649' of type [or         g.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with nam         e '(inner bean)#207b8649': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:          No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
07:34:42.549 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bot' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/bot/Bot.class]: Unsatisfied dependency          expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'channelService' defined in URL [jar:file:/r         oot/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/service/ChannelService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce         ption: Error creating bean with name 'jpaChannelRepository' defined in com.nikita.repository.JpaChannelRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on App: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#         207b8649' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error c         reating bean with name '(inner bean)#207b8649': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBean         DefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at com.nikita.App.main(App.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'channelService' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/service/ChannelS         ervice.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaChannelRepos         itory' defined in com.nikita.repository.JpaChannelRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on App: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#207b8649' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.Shared         EntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#207b8649': Canno         t resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFact         ory' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaChannelRepository' defined in com.nikita.repository.JpaChannelRepository defined in @EnableJpaReposito         ries declared on App: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#207b8649' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org         .springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#207b8649': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nes         ted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#207b8649': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor          argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:690)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
        ... 54 common frames omitted
root@dsde1081-22288:~#  ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
ERROR: command not found
root@dsde1081-22288:~# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bot' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/bot/Bot.class]: Unsatisfied dependency          expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'channelService' defined in URL [jar:file:/r         oot/telegramBotMoney.jar!/com/nikita/service/ChannelService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce         ption: Error creating bean with name 'jpaChannelRepository' defined in com.nikita.repository.JpaChannelRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on App: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#         207b8649' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error c         reating bean with name '(inner bean)#207b8649': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBean         DefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
-bash: !/com/nikita/bot/Bot.class]: event not found
```

ChannelService, в котором возникает ошибка:

```html
import com.nikita.model.Channel;
import com.nikita.repository.JpaChannelRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ChannelService {

    private final JpaChannelRepository channelRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ChannelService(JpaChannelRepository channelRepository) {
        this.channelRepository = channelRepository;
    }


    public List<Channel> findByStart(boolean start){
        return channelRepository.findAllByStart(start);
    }

    public Channel update(Channel channel){
        return channelRepository.save(channel);
    }

    public void delete(String id){
        channelRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public List<Channel> findAll(){
        return channelRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Channel findById(String id){
        return channelRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

Репозиторий:

```html
import com.nikita.model.Channel;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface JpaChannelRepository extends JpaRepository<Channel, String> {

    @Override
    Optional<Channel> findById(String id);

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Channel c WHERE c.start=:start")
    List<Channel> findAllByStart(@Param("start") boolean start);

    @Override
    <S extends Channel> S save(S s);

    @Override
    void deleteById(String id);


}
```

Когда на локальной машине запускаю это приложение, оно отрабатывает без ошибок, но при попытке запустить на vps сразу вылетают эти ошибки

Comment: На локальной машине - это в смысле в IDE? Пробовали запустить jar'ник так, как он запускается на VPS? Судя по ошибке "No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available" приложение не видит зависимостей.

Comment: Да, через IDE, но почему только в ChanelService, другие дины он находит по стекрейсу. Запустить через консоль на локальной машине вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Возможно, у вас что-то не то с БД на сервере. Проверьте, что она работает и подключение к ней верно указано